# PHP Dates getting a start date and end date for each period

Tags: php, date

Okay I'm trying to generate the end of the billing period from one date; my question is if I have a variable `$billing_period = 02/28/2016` and the billing periods are on every `14th` and `28th` of each month. from this one variable how can I generate the end date of the period when they have different days appart depending on the start date?

What's confusing to me is that if the date is the `28th` it has either `15` or `16`days apart from the `14th` which is the start of the next billing period. And if the date is the `14th` then it has 14 days apart from the `28th`. Thanks for any help

**EDIT**
- The image here shows the date which is selected which is the `02/14/2016` how can I echo the next billing date which would be `02/28/2016` from just the start date

[image]

This is my code for the array and getting the start date.

```
<?
    $date = array('16-01-14','16-01-28','16-02-14','16-02-28','16-03-14','16-03-28','16-04-14','16-04-28',
'16-05-14','16-05-28','16-06-14','16-06-28','16-07-14','16-07-28','16-08-14','16-08-28','16-09-14','16-09-28','16-10-14','16-10-28',
'16-11-14','16-11-28','16-12-14','16-12-28');
    $currentdate = date('y-m-d');
 foreach ($date as $i => $d) {
    if ($currentdate >= $d && ($i == count($date)-1 || $currentdate < $date[$i+1])) {
        $selected = "selected";
        $selected_int = $i;
    } else {
        $selected = "";
    }
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $d);
    echo "<option $selected>" . date("m/d/Y", strtotime($d)) . "</option>";
 }
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Comment: @NoyGabay I will add some more information

Comment: You only have two day dates to worry about, and you can get the month from any given date. It shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Popnoodles yes that's the question, I'm asking how I can do that when I only have the start date to work with.

Comment: You know if the start date is on the 14 or the 28. It only needs one switch or one if/else. You don't need to be concerned about the actual difference in days between the dates.

Comment: @Popnoodles pretty much all of the dates shown above have a difference in days apart so the days apart i should be concerned about. If it was as simple as an if statement for the `14th` and a if statement for the `28th` I would have done that but its not.

Comment: It certainly reads like it is, and that you're making it complicated for no reason. Or is your question "How do I calculate the amount of days between two dates?"

Comment: @LewisTyler it might help if you add some code to your question. You already have all of the billing dates as they're displayed in the select. From my understanding, all you need to do is get the date which proceeds the one selected, and get the difference in days

Comment: @billyonecan Thanks billy for the response I have added the array on how I get the start date.

Comment: (Now with code). Ok so you have a list. Surely inside `if ($currentdate...){` this would get you the next date like this `$nextdate = $date[$i + 1];`

Comment: @Popnoodles :) thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build an array with the billing dates, get the current key and increment it to get the next value. Simple example with strings:

```
$dates    = ['02/28/2016', '03/14/2016', '03/28/2016', ...];
$key      = array_search( '03/14/2016', $dates );
$nextDate = $dates[$key + 1]; // 03/28/2016
```

Is this what you want to get?

Comment: thankyou for an answer; I will defiantly mark this as the answer if you could apply it to the example above :) thankyou really appreciate the help

Comment: You can easily use `$selected_int` which equals the `$key` variable. Use `$date[$selected_int + 1]` to get the next date and it's done

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understood well.

What you are trying to do is determine which is your billing period depending on the date you previously selected.

So, you select a date ($date).

Then you need to know the selected day

```
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$day = date('D', $timestamp);
```

Now that you have your day you can make the comparations.

```
$datetime = new DateTime($date);
if ($day == 14 ){ // if you select 14th then your billing is on the 28th 
    $billing = $datetime->modify($date->format('Y-m-28'));
}else{ // if you didn't select 14th, then you select 28, and you add one month and set the day in 14th.
    $next_month = $datetime->modify('+1 month');
    $billing = $next_month->modify($date->format('Y-m-14'));
}
```

Comment: This is what I perceive to be the question to be too, even though Lewis says it's not...

Comment: Nice answer jpganz18 exactly what I was looking for thankyou.

Comment: I forgot to remove the && at the if clause, be sure you see the updates

Answer (score 0):

Here the code to get you the next date, just in case you want to do it as a one off.

```
$date = new DateTime();

$next = $date->format('14/m/Y');
if ($date->format('d') >= 14 && $date->format('d') < 28) {
    $next = $date->format('28/m/Y');
}

if ($date->format('d') >= 28) {
    $date->modify('+1 month');
    $next = $date->format('14/m/Y');
}

echo $next;
```

Here's the code turned into the function which you can call whenever you need it, it'll return a `DateTime()` object so you can output the date in whatever format you need at the time, or perform further comparisons/modifications should you need to down the line.

```
function nextBillingDate($date, $format = 'd/m/Y') {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    $next = $date->format('14/m/Y');
    if ($date->format('d') >= 14 && $date->format('d') <= 28) {
        $next = $date->format('28/m/Y');
    }

    if ($date->format('d') >= 28) {
        $date->modify('+1 month');
        $next = $date->format('14/m/Y');
    }

    return DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $next);
}
```

Example use:

```
$date = nextBillingDate('28/02/2016');
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Outputs:

> 14/03/2016

Hope it helps.